# Please help me understand why mutate does this

Tags: r, dplyr, rep

I have a dataframe "dat2" of 40 obs x 3 variables. I want to add a column "tx", based on 2 vectors: "treatments" (5 elements) and "ET" (4 elements).

```
treatments <- c("ctrl", "204", "226", "204+226", "blina")
ET <- c("10:1", "5:1", "2.5:1", "T only")
```

If I combine the vectors like this:

```
rep(rep(treatments, each=2), length(ET))
```

I get a vector of length = 40, as desired.

```
> rep(rep(treatments, each=2), length(ET))
 [1] "ctrl"    "ctrl"    "204"     "204"     "226"     "226"     "204+226"
 [8] "204+226" "blina"   "blina"   "ctrl"    "ctrl"    "204"     "204"    
[15] "226"     "226"     "204+226" "204+226" "blina"   "blina"   "ctrl"   
[22] "ctrl"    "204"     "204"     "226"     "226"     "204+226" "204+226"
[29] "blina"   "blina"   "ctrl"    "ctrl"    "204"     "204"     "226"    
[36] "226"     "204+226" "204+226" "blina"   "blina"
```

However, if I use that same line inside mutate:

```
mutate(dat2, tx = rep(rep(treatments, each=2), length(ET)))
```

it doesn't work, as it seems to generate 400 elements:

```
Error: Column `tx` must be length 40 (the number of rows) or one, not 400
```

I know I could just work around by creating a vector with the reps and then using that vector to define 'tx' inside mutate, but I want to understand why 'rep' behaves differently inside mutate.

Thanks!!

Comment: The stricter behavior is an intentional feature -- the developers of tidyverse wanted to avoid situations where invisible assumptions are made "for convenience," such as repeating a vector to fit the data frame, that produce behavior that might not be obvious. Makes sense but can certainly cause extra work for the coder sometimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `mutate` expects the length of the output to be the same as the number of rows.  If it is not that, it will throw error.  We can wrap it in a `list` and then `unnest` to expand the `list` column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat2 %>%
    summarise(tx = list(rep(rep(treatments, each=2), length(ET))))  %>%
    unnest(c(tx))
```

Comment: Thanks. But the output of rep(rep(treatments, each=2), length(ET)) is 40. Why does it become 400?

Comment: @user10577351 if you need a single instance use `summarise`.  Sorry, forgot to change your `mutate`

Comment: @user10577351 i corrected that, can you please check that